# Should I install Ubuntu on a Logical Volume?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, raid

newbie here. I've also searched the forums and read some related opinions etc but wanted to double check and make sure I was understanding stuff correctly and how it applies to my specific circumstance.

A physical volume is like the actual physical disk drive. A logical volume is when you combine or divide multiple physical disk drives under the presentation of a single virtual disk drive. Correct?

### SHORT VERSION:

Without doing too much explaining here's my questions:

1. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on to a Logical Volume which is made of 2 SSDs and 1 HDD?
2. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a Logical volume which is made of 2 SSDs and 2HDDs which are Raided together for backup protection
3. Is it possible for a Windows installation to see the logical volumes?

### Long Version for background

I am converting my home desktop into a cloud-backup/media server. I have these drives on my home desktop:

- 250GB SSD
- 111GB SSD
- 500GB HDD
- 2.75TB HDD
- 2.75TB HDD

Then I also have 500gb SSD for my Windows only Surface Book 2 laptop which I use mostly at work.

I want to divide my work files into 2 categories: "Current Working Projects" and "Archive".

My aim is to have all my current working projects files on my laptop and then backed-up automatically via NextCloud to my desktop, and then use the larger storage on my desktop to make all Archive files accessible from the web, as needed.

The reason I want to have as many of the drives grouped together is so that when I save stuff etc in the partition I'm not having to think about my file structure in relation to the physical division of the drives.

I'd like it so that when I go to my home folder I can stuff divide like this

*  = only on desktop
** = on desktop and laptop

- Documents **

  - DailyMedia
- Work **

  - 2D Projects
  - 3D Projects
  - Web Dev
  - Game Dev
  - Video Projects
- Media *

  - Movies
  - TV Shows
  - Music
  - Games
- Work Archive *

  - 2D Projects
  - 3D Projects
  - Web Dev
  - Game Dev
  - Video Project

I don't want to come to a point where downloading a certain large GB game means saving that particular game away from all the others, nor do I want it to mean I have to move the entire Games folder over to a random other drive in order to fit the game in there.

### ----------

---

Depending on what the answers to the above questions are I see several options:

1. Install

   - Ubuntu LV-{250gb ssd, 500gb, 2.75gb RAID}
   - Windows on {111GB} but it has access to the 2.75gb if it needs.
2. Install

   - Ubuntu on a LV-{250gb ssd, 111gb, 2.75tb RAID}
   - Windows {500GB}
3. Install

   - Ubuntu LV-{250gb ssd, 500GB}
   - Archive drive {2.75gb RAID with root symlinked into the Home Directory of Ubuntu and also Windows}
   - Windows on {111gb}.

---

#### Which of those are possible and which do you think is best?

Comment: If I put my archive HDD raided drives on the LV will they be visible to Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on to a Logical Volume which is made of 2 SSDs and 1 HDD?*

Yes. HOWEVER if any of those drives fails, Ubuntu will not boot and will not be recoverable. You are far better off with RAID-1 and moving archives off into other drives when you need space. Hardware is cheap, your time is precious. Back up often, even if you have a RAID-1 rig.

*2. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a Logical volume which is made of 2 SSDs and 2HDDs which are Raided together for backup protection.*

Harnessing HDDs and SSDs together is like trying to plow a field with a Corvette and a mule;  EXTREMELY risky because the HDDs will be out of sync with the SSDs very, very often. Make a volume with two SSDs, and another volume with two HDDs, and back up offsite anyway.

*3. Is it possible for a Windows installation to see the logical volumes?*

If formatted using FAT32 or NTFS, yes. There is an [ext2 file system driver](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) for Windows, but it never has been stable for me and has corrupted volumes multiple times in my experience. [Microsoft even agrees with me](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

--

And, please, henceforth, pose one question at a time, following https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks that is good to know. So it sounds like for the purposes of safety I should do something like the 3rd option I listed except with the symlinks etc? That way I will have the backup drives still available from my Home menu but in case of something breaking, the damage will be limited to specific physical drives.